# Creating Tabs in Google Docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I know in Google Sheets you can compile multiple spreadsheets by using the tab feature at the bottom. I was wondering if there is any way to do this with Google Docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if it's possible to have tabs in Docs same as in Sheets like these:

[image: 0]

...unfortunately, that is **not** possible.

---

On the other hand, you can setup **Outlines** (which is not the same as tabs/sheets in Sheets, but it could be handy to fast-jump on specific spots)

[image: 0]